how to override a property in spring properties files?
I have a regular Java web application that uses Spring (not Spring boot) and it uses context parameter named contextConfigLocation to configure spring beans:
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      classpath:dao-common.xml
      classpath:dao.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

The dao-common.xml is packaged inside a third party jar used by the web app and dao.xml is packaged in the webapp itself. I can edit dao.xml but not dao-common.xml
I am trying to "override" the bean definitions provided inside dao-common.xml with the bean definitions defined in dao.xml as follows:
Bean definition in dao-common.properties:
<bean id="dbprops"
        class="DBProps">
        <constructor-arg value="" />
</bean>

Override this definition in dao.properties:
<bean id="dbprops"
        class="DBProps">
        <constructor-arg value="something else" />
</bean>

But Spring is creating the dbprops bean with constructor arg "" instead of "something else". Is there any way to make spring use the definition from dao.xml while instantiating dbprops bean?

Set the Loading Order in contextConfigLocation:
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:dao-common.xml
        classpath:dao.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

this will ensure dao.xml is loaded last overriding any bean definition from dao-common
